# Getting the file used by a FileInputStream

Tags: java, file, file-io, fileinputstream

Is it possible to obtain the `File` being used by a `FileInputStream`? `FileInputStream` does not appear to have any methods for retrieving it.

Comment: you can use reflections as shown in my answer, have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no direct methods in `FileInputStream` API, but if you really wanted, you can use java reflection API to get the `path` (actual file name with full path) as shown below:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
Field field = fis.getClass().getDeclaredField("path");
field.setAccessible(true);
String path  = (String)field.get(fis);
System.out.println(path);
```

The `path` variable (holds the file name with path) is declared in the `FileInputStream` class as a private final field, which we are getting it using reflections code as shown above.

**P.S.:** **You need to NOTE that the above approach can't be guaranteed to achieve the result across all of the JVM implementations as it is not defined in the specification.**

Comment: This only works for implementations of `FileInputStream` that have such a member. There's nothing in the contract that requires it.

Comment: In fact I cannot find such a field in JDK 1.6, 1.7, or 1.8, for either `FileInputStream` or `FileOutputStream`. Have you tested this?

Comment: yes, I tested this, works fine

Comment: Also, just looked at the class file which shows this variable: private final String path;

Comment: Which version? Not present in the ones I mentioned. 1.7 and 1.8 are OpenJDK, the other is src.zip as distributed with the JDK. It seems to me that you're looking at `java.io.File`. There is no reason why `FileInputStream` should store a `path` variable. It isn't needed beyond the constructor.

Comment: 1.8 version of the JDK, used my eclipse decompiler