# How to get the Excel file name using workbook of Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, fileinputstream

I am working in an application, where user needs to upload an Excel sheet, like *.xls* files or *.xlsx* files. 
I am using below code to get the workbook from **FileInputStream**,

```
Workbook wb = null;
wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStreamObj);
```

My question is, how can I get the exact file name which has been uploaded, from this workbook object ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not get it from the `FileInputStream` which does know?

Comment: How can I get the file name from **FileInputStream** , as well? I didn't get any clue on that too from internet.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700958/getting-the-file-used-by-a-fileinputstream

Comment: They used Reflection to get path of the file. Okay thank you.